# Verify ability to login to server via jumpbox for application support (ssh multiple hops)

Tags: linux, unix, authentication, ssh, ssh-keys

I am due to go on application support shortly and one of the steps in order to do that is to verify that I can login to all of our application nodes.

In order to login to an application node, you first need to login to a jumpbox, then from here you need to login to the application node.

All login is done via ssh.

- ssh user@jumpbox
- ssh user@applicationnode
- uname -a - > Verified login

This is going to be a neanderthal task that will occur on roughly 1000 nodes.

Consequently I am trying to automate the process.

I have tried using Fabric library in Python, setting up a gateway to point at the jumpbox, but I still get prompted for password, which would take away from the automation.

Is this automated in the industry by any devops tools?

Answer (score 0):

this has two answers: one for the future, and one for now.

**Doing automated remote login *correctly***

In the future you should generate a public/private key pair, and list the public key in your remote user's `.ssh/authorized` keys. That will make access password-less, if your local SSH uses the right private key to authenticate:

```
rsa-keygen -t rsa -f deploykey
cp deploykey .ssh/id_rsa
#and insert the content of deploykey.pub into the remote user's .ssh/authorized keys
```

**Doing mass access using password**

Now, I don't know which OS you're using, but just assuming you're using a linux or *BSD
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/ will allow you to non-interactively supply your password.

Comment: Im not sure sshpass is viable here as I cannot install this on the jumpbox. I can install it locally, but how do I execute ssh twice using this command without a prompt.